# Can you create a View of a database Share, as a consumer?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a View of a database share (I am the consumer of the share).

e.g.

```sql
create view testview as (select * from myshare);
```

results in this error:

`SQL execution error: Creating view on shared database 'myshare' is not allowed.`

I didn't see any conclusive documentation around this. If this is not allowed, are there any workarounds to accomplish a similar outcome?

Comment: Is “myshare” a database? If it is then your view creation statement makes no sense - you can only create views that query tables/views

Comment: It's a table, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: So you need to create the view in a writeable database that references the table in the db created from the share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a view (or any other object) in the shared database as it is read-only reflection of the providers database.

You can create a view in another [`database.schema`] that references it.

Heres an example using ZEPL's US_STOCK_DAILY share from the Snowflake Marketplace.

So this fails, as you have found:

```
Use Database US_STOCKS_DAILY;
Use Schema PUBLIC;

Create View MAX_DATE as 
Select max(DATE)  MAXDATE from STOCK_HISTORY;

SQL execution error: Creating view on shared database 'US_STOCKS_DAILY' is not allowed.
```

But this works.

```
Use Database MY_DATABASE ;
Use Schema MY_SCHEMA;

Create View MAX_DATE as 
Select max(DATE)  MAXDATE 
  from US_STOCKS_DAILY.PUBLIC.STOCK_HISTORY; 

Select max(DATE) MAXDATE from MAX_DATE;
```

Note, you need to fully-qualify the object name in the providers schema.